# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am doing inline edit with `delete`,`cancel` and `update` buttons.When I try to cancel the edit its showing error as `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`.
What is mistake in my code?

```
function editCancel(id) {
    var cancelId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + cancelId).hide();
    var number = cancelId.replace("editCancel", "");
    $("#update" + number).hide();
    $("#edit" + number).show();
    $("#delete" + number).show();

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zs0hqv3e/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem area is `this` in the function, it refers to *window* object not the button which invoked the function.

Modify your function

```
function editCancel(elem) {
    var cancelId = $(elem).attr('id');
    //rest of code
}
```

Pass the current element in the inline click handler like

```
<button class="btn editCancel btn-danger" onclick="editCancel(this)"></button>
```

[Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs0hqv3e/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation for binding events to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', ".editCancelAction", function (){
  //Your code.
  var cancelId = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#" + cancelId).hide();
  var number = cancelId.replace("editCancel", "");
  $("#update" + number).hide();
  $("#edit" + number).show();
  $("#delete" + number).show();
});
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zs0hqv3e/4/

Comment: Can I use more than one `$(document).on()` method?.

Comment: But its taking more time to load the page.I have four buttons,can I use separate `$(document).on()` method for each and every buttons?

Comment: @krish you can but you don't need to. Code will be clean if you reduce those extra lines of code.